# How can I refactor methods that return different types of List

Tags: java, csv, generics

I have four methods which are doing very similar things. They read a CSV file and return a list, but with different types. I want to refactor them, but I don't know how to do it. Maybe someone can help.

Here is my code:

```
public List<PersonFirstName> readPersonFirstNames(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(path.toString());
    CsvToBean<PersonFirstName> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<PersonFirstName>(reader)
            .withType(PersonFirstName.class)
            .withSeparator(';')
            .build();

    return csvToBean.parse();
}

public List<Street> readStreets(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(path.toString());
    CsvToBean<Street> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Street>(reader)
            .withType(Street.class)
            .withSeparator(';')
            .build();

    return csvToBean.parse();
}

public List<City> readCities(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(path.toString());
    CsvToBean<City> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<City>(reader)
            .withType(City.class)
            .withSeparator(';')
            .build();

    return csvToBean.parse();
}

public List<PersonLastName> readPersonLastNames(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(path.toString());
    CsvToBean<PersonLastName> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<PersonLastName>(reader)
            .withType(PersonLastName.class)
            .withSeparator(';')
            .build();

    return csvToBean.parse();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve from the refactoring? Do you want to have a single method for all the types?

Comment: yes i want to create a method that i can call in these 4 methods so my code becomes less

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T> List<T> read(Path path, Class<T> clazz) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(path.toString());
    CsvToBean<T> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(reader)
            .withType(clazz)
            .withSeparator(';')
            .build();

    return csvToBean.parse();
}
```

This method shares common logic of reading and accepts class of result type as additional parameter.

Example of usage:

```
public List<PersonFirstName> readPersonFirstNames(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return read(path, PersonFirstName.class);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice